# Cannot use this.props or set this.state in function outside Render

Tags: reactjs, typescript, state, this, react-props

First post and new to react.

I am having an issue whereby when I try to use a `prop` in a function outside the render it is `undefined` and when trying to use it to set a state value, it does not work.

I have read up about this and have found many answers, mainly that the all functions should be bound to the class or use the arrow method so when referring to `this` inside the function it refers to the class.

None of these seem to work.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Below is the code I am using.

I call the `EntryForm` component from another component passing the value 5 in `userDetails.Id`.

```
export interface UserDetails {
    Id: string;
}

export interface IProps {
    userDetails: UserDetails
}

export interface IState {
    combinedURL: string;
}

export default class EntryForm extends React.Component<IProps, IState> {

    constructor(props : IProps) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            combinedURL: 'MonkeyFace12' as string
        };
        this.createCombinedURL = this.createCombinedURL.bind(this);
    } 

    async createCombinedURL() {
        try {
            this.setState({ combinedURL: 'This is the Start of the URL followed by ' + this.props.userDetails.Id });
        } catch (e) {
            console.log("Error setting CombinedURL");
        }
    }

    async componentDidMount() {
        try {
            await this.createCombinedURL();
        } catch (error) {
        }
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <>
                <FormGroup row>
                    <Label
                        sm={1}>
                        Client
                    </Label>
                </FormGroup>

                <Button color="primary" type="submit">
                    Sign in
                </Button>
            </>
        );
    }
}
```

When I check the value of `this.state.CombinedURL` it is still MonkeyFace12.

The function `CreateCombinedURL` does not seem to affect it at all.

Comment: So if I am getting you properly you saying that when you call **this.setate** it does not work? Lastly if you are new to React why don't you use plain JavaScript till you comfortable with React than you can add TypeScript.

Comment: Hi and many thanks for your reply. Yes, when it runs the command this.setState({ combinedURL: 'This is the Start of the URL followed by ' + this.props.userDetails.Id }); it does not set the combinedURL state. It stays as MonkeyFace12. Also during debugging, this.props.userDetails.Id evaluates to "undefined".

Comment: I understand what your are saying but piece of advise when your freshly new into React do not try and add TypeScript to the mix you just putting yourself down a rabbit hole

Answer (score 0):

I was like you not long ago. I actually found that using arrow functions works a log smoother for a lot of the situations that I came across, and I came from Java where classes are key.

Using an arrow functions and hooks look a lot neater in my opinion as well. You don't have to worry about the 'this.' keyword at all. Hooks are amazing tools that also replace some of the lifecycle methods as well. Below is just an example of how much cleaner it can be.

```
import React, { FC, useState } from 'react'

interface IProps {
   username: string
}

const EntryForm: FC<IProps> = ({username}) => {
   const [combinedURL, setCombinedURL] = useState('Start of the URL here +')//sets up state for you without extra work
   
   useEffect(() => {
      //do something to the state
      setCombinedURL(combinedURL + username)
   }, [])//This dependency array determines when this method fires. Empty means it runs only once.

   return(
      <div>
         This is the combined URL {combinedURL}
         <input type='text' onChange={e => {
            setCombinedURL(e.target.value); //Or whatever else you want to happen.
         }}>
      </div>
   )

}
```

Comment: BTW, using functions inside this is easy as well. One newbie to another.